# How to suspend another process before it executes main

Tags: c++, windows, suspend

In Windows, I can use the C++ interface IWbemObjectSink to monitor the launch of a process. I can know a target process is launched in the virtual function  Indicate(...), and I suspend the target process immediately when it is launched. But I find the target process has executed something before it is suspended.

How can I suspend the target process before it executes its main()?

Thanks a lot!

I expect a good way to suspend the target process before it executes its main().

Comment: I'm assuming you're not starting the process yourself? Because if so, you could just pass `CREATE_SUSPENDED` to `CreateProcess`.

Comment: Run it in a debugger. Also, a program can do plenty of stuff before entering `main`, while its statics are initialized. In fact, the program could in theory perform its entire job with an empty `main` function.

Comment: You could check out [PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/nf-ntddk-pssetcreateprocessnotifyroutineex). Your program must execute in kernel mode (_i.e._ be a driver). And it's unclear from this documentation what actions can be taken at this point (when the process is not yet created).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.